# If image exists show else hide it

Tags: php

I have the following situation.

If there isn't an image in the DB, the page it's on shows a big image placeholder.  What is the best way to hide the image placeholder if an image doesn't exist?

```
<img src="<?php echo '../img/artists/' . $row_rsAccents['artistPhoto']; ?>" width="100%"/>
```

http://westerndesignconference.com/intheloop/

Comment: You could always try using an [`if`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)-[`else`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php) statement to either show or hide the `<img>` :)

Comment: Don't you know how to add a simple if statement? If not then I suggest you to read the manual or read a book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple if/else statement like so:

```
//I prefer to set things with variables
$placeholder_img = "../img/artists/placeholder.jpg";
$db_img = $row_rsAccents['artistPhoto'];

if($db_img){
    $img_src = $db_img;
} else {
    $img_src = $placeholder_img;
}

echo "<img src='$img_src' alt='' width='100%' />";
```

Comment: nice approach, I prefer if you echo out the img tag tho

Comment: No problem - if this answers your question, please set as answered. 
@meda I have edited my answer to echo the img tag.

Comment: yeah this is the problem I've been having it's still loading the spacer gif at 100%...

Comment: You could move the echo inside the if statement like so:
`if($db_img){
    $img_src = $db_img;
    echo "<img src='$img_src' alt='' width='100%' />";
} else {
    $img_src = $placeholder_img;
    echo "<img src='$img_src' alt='' />";
}`

Answer (score 1):

If there is a value returned - show an image. If the condition fails, no `<img>` will be displayed, preventing the blank gap

```
if (isset($row_rsAccents['artistPhoto'])) {
    echo '<img src="../img/artists/' . $row_rsAccents['artistPhoto'] . '" width="100%"/>'
}
```

Comment: Depending on the OP's database values, another method would be `if ($row_rsAccents['artistPhoto']!='') {`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file_exists('artist.jpg') {
    echo "<img src='artist.jpg'>";
}
else {
    echo "<img src='default.jpg'>";
}
```

Comment: @meda Yes, it seems so: "if there isn't an image in the DB"